# List does not display in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

[image]I am making a dynamic list, but it is not displayed. Why?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mFScX/4/

```
function buildNavForNodes(nodes) {
    console.log(nodes);
  var result = '<div data-role="collapsible"> <ul>';
  var i = 0;
  var len = nodes.length;
  for(; i < len; i++) {
    result += buildNavForNode(nodes[i]);
  }
  return result + " </ul></div>";
}
```

It should be displayed like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Dn4XB/4/

Button array have three object :
It mean three Collapsible row display.

```
**Button
Button
Button**
```

Now Button array index at 0 object have button array .[image]

So In index zero have button have another collapsible row.

Comment: Seems to display just fine for me? Did you mean you're not getting the right values from the JSON.

Comment: No it should be collapsible like this http://jsfiddle.net/Dn4XB/4/

Comment: You are not adding the html elements in the correct order for the collapsible list to display correctly.

Comment: can you change fiddle ?

Comment: I showed you how the HTML should be laid out in the fiddle you provided in these comments. You need the <div data-role="collapsible"> as the container and an <h1> tag immediately after. If you want to add list elements after the <h1> tag you need to need to include <ul data-role="listview">

Comment: ok trying...it your fiddle worrking

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mFScX/5/ Not working  in my fiddle

Comment: @Clayton Not working my side.Is it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Most probably you want something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mFScX/8/)):</strike>

```
function buildNav(nodes) {
    var i = 0, len = nodes.length, result;
    for(; i < len; i++) {
        result ='<div data-role="collapsible"><h1><a>Button</a></h1><ul>';
        if(!nodes[i].Button) result += '<li><h3>Button</h3></li></ul></div>';
        else result += buildNav(nodes[i].Button);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's right but, `.trigger('create')` should be called after you insert the `HTML`.

**Update: ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dn4XB/9/))**

```
function buildNav(nodes) {
    var result = '<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="stuff">';
    var i = 0, len = nodes.length;
    for(; i < len; i++) {
        result += "<div data-role='collapsible' data-content-theme='c'><h3><a>Button</a></h3>";
        if(nodes[i].Button) {
            result += buildNav(nodes[i].Button) + "</div>";
        }
        result += "</div>";
    }
    return result + "</div>";
}

$(function(){
    $('#test').html(buildNav(testData.Button)).trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: Maybe I can but it looks quite a big one :-)

Comment: if you do that I will be thankfull to you .I need gratefull to you.The reult should same .collapsed row have some contend .i already make function.

Comment: It looks working, I didn't get it yet, anyways, can you gimme more information, maybe post another question with example and real object.

Comment: Please let me know any any issue

Answer (score -1):

Each collapsible container needs to look somewhat like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
     <h1><a>Button</a></h1>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a>Button</a></li>
            </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Why are you downvoting? I showed you how to get the collapsible content with the Fiddle you posted in the OP and have told you how to get it to work properly in the context of your function. I'm not sure what more you want?

Comment: @cyayton becuse it is not generated dynamically .I used your concept it not word